# About Argument of complex numbers

Tags: complex

Suppose my `z = x + iy`
Now, if `y=0`, then `z = x` i.e it becomes a real number
So, logically `Arg[z]` should be equal to zero for this case.

If I assign the numeric value for `x`, then `Arg[z]` produces zero in *Mathematica* easily. But if I do not assign the numeric value for `x` which is of course a real number always, then how to produce `Arg[z]=0` for this case ?  Because assigning or not assigning numeric value to `x` should not prevent Argument of `z` to be zero i.e `Arg[z]=0`.

Actually, my computation involves variables only i.e algebraic expressions, no numeric calculations. The final *Mathematica* output has a term `Arg[r]`. The parameter `r` , radius, is always real. So, *Mathematica* should understand that as `r` is always real number, so `Arg[r]` should be zero. Please guide me how to achieve this.   (Pranjol Paul, Department of Mechanical Engineering, Indian Institute of Technology Guwahati, Assam, India)

Comment: Note: `x` is (undefined) understood to be complex in Mathematica. Also be aware that the `Arg` of a real is not always 0, e.g. `Arg[-1]` is `Pi`...; you might want to look at `$Assumptions` etc, e.g. as in `Refine[Arg[y], y >= 0]`

Comment: @PinguinDirk:`Arg` is only for positive side of x-axis and has significance only in complexes.

Comment: @Blackbird, I am afraid I don't understand your comment. As reals are a subset of complexes, `Arg` is defined there too, see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis). Thus, multiplying $i*i=-1$ you directly see that the real number $-1$ must have argument $\pi$ (as $i$ has $\pi/2$)

Comment: @PinguinDirk:`Arg[-n]` will be `Pi` because the y-component sits on -x and in case of -x it makes 180 Degrees from origin starting from +ive x-axis.Tan[0]=Tan[Pi]...that's why `Im` is needed.

Answer (score 7):

To get rid of this unanswered question (and I do not really agree with @Blackbird's answer, see comments above), I shall put my comment in an answer:

Note: `x` is (undefined) understood to be complex in Mathematica. 
Also be aware that the `Arg` of a real is not always $0$, e.g. `Arg[-1]` is `Pi`...; 
you might want to look at `$Assumptions` etc, e.g. as in `Refine[Arg[y], y >= 0]`

Please comment if it doesn't help - if there are further questions!

(now let's hope someone will upvote this (or the other answer) so there is one less question on the list)

Answer (score 0):

In `M` all symbolics are considered to support Complex numbers and obviously Real are special cases of complexes.

```
z = x + y I
```

> x + I y

```
Head[%]      (*Plus*)
Head[z /. {x -> 3, y -> 0}]
```

> Integer         (*Not anymore complex*)

```
Head[z /. {x -> 3, y -> 0.}]
```

> Complex  (*It considers only approx to zero as complex *)

```
Arg[3. + 0. I]
```

> 0 . (*It return approx to Zero not zero*)

And what is the meaning of calculating `Arg` if the expression itself is not Complex anymore if you substitute your Imaginary part as 0